# Python : check length of list and run method for each item or sublist after first element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do something like below in python 2.7

Example 1:

```
mylist  = ['or', 'A', 'B', 'C']

tree1 = my_method(mylist[1])   #A
tree2 = my_method(mylist[2])   #B 
tree3 = my_method(mylist[3])   #C

return ['or', tree1, tree2, tree3]
```

**Problem is there can be any number of elements in list and I want to compute tree*X* for each of them and then return as many tree*X* that we computed.** In above example there are 3 trees so there are 3 trees in return.

Example 2:

```
mylist  = ['or', ['and','A','B','C'], 'B']

tree1 = my_method(mylist[1])   #['and','A','B','C']
tree2 = my_method(mylist[2])   #B

return ['or', tree1, tree2]
```

In above example there are 2 trees as there are 2 sub-elements so there are 2 trees in return.

How can this be done in python?
Thanks!

Comment: downvoters, please add comments to help the OP post a better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this you can use a list comprehension to apply a method to the items of a list:

```
def process_list(mylist):
    return mylist[:1] + [my_method(item) for item in mylist[1:]]

mylist  = ['or', ['and','A','B','C'], 'B']
print(process_list(mylist))
```

Comment: List comprehension really helps to reduce the amount of code and made my program more clean. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I couldn't explain requirement clearly. I figured out solution below using a loop. The tricky thing was I didn't know we can add 2 lists using + in python. I just started learning python.

```
            length = len(prop)
            i = 1
            tmp = []
            op = 'or'
            while i < length:
                tree = implies(prop[i]) 
                tmp.append(tree)
                i = i + 1

            answer = [op] + tmp [:]
            return answer
```